# check if caret at the end of document

Tags: wpf, document, caret

I want to check if RichTextBox.CaretPosition is at the end of the document.

[Image shows problem](http://s18.postimg.org/eclzjywqh/Bez_tytu_u.png)

I have this code.

```
public void SetFormatInRichTextBox(RichTextBox rich,Color color,string property)
{
        if (IsPositionContainedBetween(rich.CaretPosition, ((Paragraph)rich.Document.Blocks.LastBlock).Inlines.LastInline.ContentStart, ((Paragraph)rich.Document.Blocks.LastBlock).Inlines.LastInline.ContentEnd))
        {

        }
}
public bool IsPositionContainedBetween(TextPointer positionToTest, TextPointer start, TextPointer end)
{

        if (!positionToTest.IsInSameDocument(start) || !positionToTest.IsInSameDocument(end))
            return false;

        return start.CompareTo(positionToTest) <= 0 && positionToTest.CompareTo(end) <= 0;
}
```

But, method IsPositionContainedBetween returns always true. I use WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that worked for me

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(RtbEditor.CaretPosition, RtbEditor.Document.ContentEnd);
if (textRange.IsEmpty || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textRange.Text))
{
    //caret is at the end of document           
}
```

It's just a bit of an extension from the solution Łukasz Walkowiak provided

Answer (score 1):

I have solution

```
TextRange tr=new TextRange(rich.CaretPosition,rich.CaretPosition.Paragraph.ContentEnd);
            if(tr.IsEmpty)
            {
               //caret is at the end of paragraph
            }
```